# How to build a table using HAML

Tags: ruby, haml

I trying to build a table. Here is my HAML code:

```
%table{:border => 1}
%tbody
%tr
  %td Question:
- @cust_dashboard.each do |object|
  %tr
    %td= object.question
%tr
  %td Status:
- @cust_dashboard.each do |object|
  %tr
    %td= object.status
%tr
  %td Created_at:
- @cust_dashboard.each do |object|
  %tr
    %td= object.created_at
```

All the items in the table are in one column:

[image]

I need a table with three columns:

[image]

Comment: It would help if you showed what you expect your output to look like. Saying "all items in table in one column" only hints that you want them in more than one, but do you want two or three columns? The sample data in the image could be rendered in one, two or three columns.

Comment: sorry.see edited question. I need a table in 3 columns

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't written HAML for a while, but I think you want:

```
%table{:border => 1}
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td Question:
      %td Status:
      %td Created_at:
    - @cust_dashboard.each do |object|
      %tr
        %td= object.question
        %td= object.status
        %td= object.created_at
```

When building your template, think in terms of how the data will be emitted: We'd see:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <td>
      <td>
    </tr>
```

Followed by a series of:

```
<tr>
  <td>
  <td>
  <td>
</tr>
```

(indented correctly of course) These would be each data row, three cells across.

I'd probably use `th` instead of `td` for the headers though:

```
%th Question:
%th Status:
%th Created_at:
```

Comment: No problem. HAML is a great tool for developers. I like how it simplifies the HTML, and makes it easier to visualize the overall layout of the HTML that will be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Each `tr` will start a new row, so I think you're getting what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a new row each time.

Try changing:

```
- @cust_dashboard.each do |object|
  %tr
    %td= object.question
```

to

```
- @cust_dashboard.each do |object|
  %td= object.question
```

Comment: hi - see answer ^^^ remove the %tr (and sort indent of following line) after each @cust_dashboard.each do |object|